# Snowmen's hat wave texture problem

Tags: modeling, mesh, texturing, objects, shaders

I’m doing a CG Cookie snowmen course and I’m stuck on this part https://cgcookie.com/lesson/materials-for-the-scarf-and-hat at 19:31 where he put a wave texture on top of the hat and I’m having troubles. The wave texture is acting weird on top of my hat please help.

My blend file https://pasteall.org/blend/8f88c59ef9314f1487a5ff53f46f2454

My hat topology
[image]

His hat topology
[image]

My Hat wave texture
[image]

Hat wave texture from course
[image]

[image]

Comment: Can you add an image of what's going on so we don't have to download the blend file?

Comment: Since that's a paid course there isn't much point in posting a link to it here!

Comment: I updated my post with images

Comment: @moonboots I updated my post with two more screen shots one with the course's hat topology and one with my hat topology but I don't understand my topology is like his so shouldn't I get the same result?

Comment: @moonboots no he's using the Generated output I updated my post with a screen shot of him using that input take a look five screen shots down.

Comment: Actually I was wrong, switching to Object didn't fix anything, but if the Scale value of the Wave Texture node is 5, like in the video, the problem won't be noticeable, so maybe that's why

Answer (score 0):

If the *Scale* value of the *Wave Texture* node is low the problem won't be noticeable, maybe this is what's happening in his video:

[image]

Another way to fix the problem is to use concentric circles for your topology (right hat):

[image]